# Apatche HTTP server - how to setup proxy to WildFly

Tags: apache, wildfly

Recently I was given a project that runs on Apache HTTP server and WildFly. I'm new to those technologies. I have a problem with proxy configuration on Apache side. Here is my httpd.conf VirtualHosts configuration for Apache.

```
#frontend
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    ServerName adminapp.pl
    DocumentRoot "D:\Projects\RS_front\adminapp"
    ErrorLog "d:\logs\httpd\admin_error.log"
    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.html|/img|/js|/css|/assets|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule     . /index.html [L]
</VirtualHost>

#backend proxy
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    ServerName api.adminapp.pl
    ErrorLog "d:\logs\httpd\wildflyProxy.log" 
    CustomLog "d:\logs\httpd\wildflyProxy_custom.log" combined
    ForensicLog "d:\logs\httpd\wildflyProxy_forensic.log"
    DumpIOInput On
    DumpIOOutput On
    LogLevel Debug
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    #adres aplikacji and serwerze Wildfly
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/adminapp/" timeout=600
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/adminapp/" timeout=600
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/adminapp" "/"

    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: adminapp.pl
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization,Accept,Content-Disposition"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
</VirtualHost>
```

I try to login to system through adminapp but it doesn't work. I feel completely lost with this, as I can't track any errors or logs to tell me what is wrong with this configuration.

Here is what I tracked so far (addresses adminapp.pl & api.adminapp.pl are mapped to localhost in my hosts file):

- The url that should be called on login attempt look like this http://localhost:8080/adminapp/oauth/token. When I type this url in the browser I got response from WildFly server that I provided bad login credentials and WildFly server logs exception.
- When I type url http://api.adminapp.pl/oauth/token in the browser I get same respons from server. So it seems like the proxy works.
- When I try to login through adminapp.pl, providing bad credentials to achive same error, nothing happens. I get only this line in Apache access log "POST /api.adminapp.pl/oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 200 906".
- When I configured front - adminapp.pl to connect directly to http://localhost:8080/adminapp (NO PROXY), then WildFly server logged error with bad credentials. But there was other problem on the front "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/adminapp/oauth/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.". I guess this is caused CORS so I need proxy in my configuration.

As you can see from my configuration I tried to generate as many logs as I could, but I cant find any more useful info. It also seems that Apache buffers logs in memory and dumps them to file in time intervals? Is there any way to tell Apache to log the information as soon as it receives info?

Summing up I need to set up this proxy and don't know how to troubleshoot my problem any further. Can you please advice me what could I do?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to deal with the problem. It turned out that my app was trying to POST request to http://adminapp.pl/api.adminapp.pl/oauth/token instead of http://api.adminapp.pl/oauth/token. Frontend application treated property url api.adminapp.pl relatively and I had to change it to http://api.adminapp.pl. Firefox with Firebug plugin came in handy and showed me the full POST url.